# Keras: How does reprocessing scale images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

For loading image data from disk, *Keras* is providing the `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()` method, which is documented on https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/.
I would like to use this method to load data for generating a image classifier.
https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-load-large-datasets-from-directories-for-deep-learning-with-keras/ contains some information on how to best organize the data.

The `image_dataset_from_directory()` takes a mandatory argument `image_size=(..., ...)` to give all images to the same size (which is required for further steps).
Where can I find details about how the pictures are scaled?
Would pictures with extreme ratios become distorted and negatively impact the classfier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses any of the [`tf.image.ResizeMethod`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py#L1295). You can find the source code in the Tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory).

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find the specifics on how resize is done. However it probably uses one of the methods available in cv2 which are listed below but I do not know which one.

```
[optional] flag that takes one of the following methods. INTER_NEAREST – a nearest-neighbor interpolation INTER_LINEAR – a bilinear interpolation (used by default) INTER_AREA – resampling using pixel area relation. It may be a preferred method for image decimation, as it gives moire’-free results. But when the image is zoomed, it is similar to the INTER_NEAREST method. INTER_CUBIC – a bicubic interpolation over 4×4 pixel neighborhood INTER_LANCZOS4 – a Lanczos interpolation over 8×8 pixel neighborhood
```

Of course when resized your images will become distorted. I do a lot of image classification and have not found this to be a problem. Beside that there appears to be no other choice but to have all the images be the same size.

Comment: Hi Gerry, thanks for your answer. It's already helpful to know that Keras uses `cv2`.

Comment: I do not think Keras uses cv2. I just mentioned it because it illustrates the types of resizing methods.